# Moving A Sprite At A Rotation

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a sprite image a car,

That i would like to move at a certain angle. how do i set it to move at a angle i want it to? I would like to move the sprite in the direction of the rotation.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3):

you can do it box2d body and use this function body.setTransform(target,angle);

Comment: Good suggestion! So i guess i could use sprite.getAngle(); to supply the angle of the sprite. So what does setTransform(target,angle) do? its obvious what the angle parameter does but what about the target?

Comment: target is a Vektor which you wanna move it to coordinates.

Comment: oh i see so there isnt a way i can provide the coordinates? Or it HAS to be a vector i use as the target i want the body to move too??

Comment: I would really prefer using Entity Modifiers

Answer (score 0):

With the class RotationModifier you can apply a rotation to your sprite.
Since you have an initialX, initialY as well as destinyX, destinyY; you can get difX and difY (destinyX-initialX and destinyY-initialY). The angle you want to apply is related to those values (the tangent of your angle is difY/difX). Remember this, Math is your friend.

Since you don't need the box2d extension with this solution, your app will be lighter.